# Background-color is not fully filling the div

Tags: html, css, background-color

`Background-color` is not fully filling the `div` ( I want to color the `div` between the `navbar` and the `footer`), the background color is only reaching maybe half of the page, is not filling all the way down till the end of the container.

So I hope you guys can help out on getting to the source of the issue, cause I have no idea what could be causing the problem :/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
        <title>FunPic - Share your pictures</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">

            <div id="header">
                <div id="navtext">
                    <p>FunPic - Share your pictures</p>
                </div>
                <div id="menu">
                    <ul id="navbar">
                        <li>Inicio</li>
                        <li>Subir Foto</li>
                        <li>Contacto</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="wrapper">
                <div id="content">
                    <div id="image"><img src="images/pic.jpg"></div>
                </div>
                <div id="content">
                    <div id="image"><img src="images/pic.jpg"></div>
                </div>
                <div id="content">
                    <div id="image"><img src="images/pic.jpg"></div>
                </div>
                <div id="content">
                    <div id="image"><img src="images/pic.jpg"></div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div id="footer">&copyFun Pic 2015 - Costa Rica</div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
{
    max-width: 1024px;
    color: red;
    margin: auto;
}
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
}
.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #E8E8E8;
    height: 100%;
}
#header {
    margin-bottom: 30;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
    background: #8AE6B8;
}
#navtext {
    padding: 14;
    width: 40%;
    float: left;
}
#navtext p {
    margin-left: 40%;
}
#menu {
    padding: 14;
    width: 40%;
    float: left;
}
#navbar {
    margin-left: 65px;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
#navbar li {
    list-style: none;
    margin-right: 10;
    display: inline-block;
}
#wrapper {
    margin: 30;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
#content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 40%;
    height: 600px;
    display: block;
}
#image {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#image img {
    width: 100%;
}
#footer {
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #202020;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: This is css related. Please post your stylesheet.

Comment: it is at the bottom! sorry

Comment: You gave a background-color to the container, ive it to the body to see if that fixes it

Comment: Yeah, i want the conatiner to be colored, like, the navbar being red, the container being blue and the footer being black, then the sides beyond the   1024 width will just be default white.

Answer (score 2):

Do it like this

```
#wrapper {
    background-color: #E8E8E8;
}
```

change  `#E8E8E8` to any color you want. This will only set the `background-color` property of your `div` between `navbar` and `footer` divs.

Comment: That worked, but the whole page -even that belong the 1024 width became the color stated, and what i wish is that only the container between the navbar and the footer to be colored :l

Comment: then instead of body use #wrapper like this 
`#wrapper{
    background-color: #E8E8E8;
}`

Comment: @AdrianVelez do accept it as answer if this resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got it, i noticed i was coloring the CONTAINER instead of the WRAPPER..! ugh...  i feel so dumb...